# Auto Assign Shader with Texture maps

Tags: python, shader, textures, maya, assign

I'm a bit new to Maya Python but I'll try to explain my question as detailed as possible.

I've created a script for Maya where the user can assign a shader (aiStandardSurface, etc.) to his selected object, once the user clicks the button a shader is created with all the nodes connected that he needs (ex: file nodes connected directly). Now what I want to do is to be able to plug the texture maps from the textures on the sourceimages folder and import them alongside the nodes, it's basically an Auto Shader script. But I'm struggling on where to begin with and how can I proceed correctly. If you have any ressources it would be amazing! Here is my code first.

```
from functools import partial
from maya import cmds
import os



#### FUNCTION ####

def get_texture_path():
    """ Open a file dialog to query a directory path

    Returns:
        str or None
    """
    directory_path = cmds.fileDialog2(fm=2, okc="Set")
    return directory_path


     

class UI:

    def __init__(self):

        self.main_window = cmds.window(title="UI", widthHeight=(200, 150), sizeable=True)
        self.build_ui()

    

    def build_ui(self):

        cmds.columnLayout(adjustableColumn=True, rowSpacing=5)
        cmds.text(label="Shader Template", font="boldLabelFont", height=25)
        cmds.setParent('..')

      
        cmds.setParent('..')

        cmds.columnLayout(adjustableColumn=True, rowSpacing=5)
        cmds.text(label="Select your mesh or group first,", align="center")
        cmds.text(label="then click on your desired renderer", align="center")
        cmds.setParent('..')

        mainLayout = cmds.columnLayout(w=500, h=35)
        cmds.separator()
        self.tf_shader_newname = cmds.textFieldGrp(label="Shader Name:", editable=True, parent=mainLayout)
        cmds.setParent('..')

        cmds.setParent('..')

        cmds.columnLayout(columnAttach=('both', 5), rowSpacing=10, adjustableColumn=True)
        cmds.button(label="Arnold", c=partial(self.shader_assign, "arnold"))
        cmds.button(label="Renderman", c=partial(self.shader_assign, "renderman"))

    def shader_assign(self, render_engine, texture_dir):

        selection_list = cmds.ls(sl=True)
        shader_name = cmds.textFieldGrp(self.tf_shader_newname, q=True, text=True)
        texture_directory = get_texture_path()
        if not texture_directory:
            print("User aborted the assign operation")
            return

        if render_engine == "arnold":
            arnold_create_network(shaderName=shader_name, selection_list=selection_list, texture_dir=texture_directory)
        elif render_engine == "renderman":
            rendermanAssign(shaderName=shader_name, selection_list=selection_list, texture_dir=texture_directory)
        else:
            raise RuntimeError("render engine not supported")

    def show_window(self):
        cmds.showWindow(self.main_window)
        return


# ### RENDERMAN ###
def rendermanAssign(shaderName, selection_list, texture_dir):

    # creer un shader
    myShader = cmds.shadingNode('PxrSurface', asShader=True, name=shaderName + "_Mtl")

    # creer un shading group
    myShaderSG = cmds.sets(renderable=True, noSurfaceShader=True, empty=True, name=myShader + "SG")

    # shader to shading group

    cmds.connectAttr('%s.outColor' % myShader, '%s.surfaceShader' % myShaderSG)

    # connect the nodes

    """ALBEDO NODES"""

    remap = cmds.shadingNode('PxrRemap', name='remap_albedo_' + shaderName, asTexture=True)
    hsl = cmds.shadingNode('PxrHSL', name='HSL_albedo_' + shaderName, asTexture=True)
    cc = cmds.shadingNode('PxrColorCorrect', name='color_correct_albedo_' + shaderName, asTexture=True)
    pxrtexture = cmds.shadingNode('PxrTexture', name='albedo_' + shaderName, asTexture=True)

    """SPECULAR NODES"""

    remap_spec = cmds.shadingNode('PxrRemap', name='remap_specular_' + shaderName, asTexture=True)
    hsl_spec = cmds.shadingNode('PxrHSL', name='HSL_specular_' + shaderName, asTexture=True)
    cc_spec = cmds.shadingNode('PxrColorCorrect', name='color_correct_specular_' + shaderName, asTexture=True)
    pxrtexture_spec = cmds.shadingNode('PxrTexture', name='specular_' + shaderName, asTexture=True)

    """ROUGHNESS NODES"""

    remap_roughness = cmds.shadingNode('PxrRemap', name='remap_roughess_' + shaderName, asTexture=True)
    hsl_roughness = cmds.shadingNode('PxrHSL', name='HSL_roughness_' + shaderName, asTexture=True)
    cc_roughness = cmds.shadingNode('PxrColorCorrect', name='color_correct_roughness_' + shaderName, asTexture=True)
    pxrtexture_roughness = cmds.shadingNode('PxrTexture', name='roughness_' + shaderName, asTexture=True)

    """BUMP AND NORMAL MAP NODES"""

    remap_bump_normal = cmds.shadingNode('PxrRemap', name='remap_bump_normal_' + shaderName, asTexture=True)
    pxrtexture_bump = cmds.shadingNode('PxrTexture', name='bump_normal_' + shaderName, asTexture=True)
    bump = cmds.shadingNode('PxrBump', name='bump_' + shaderName, asTexture=True)

    """DISPLACEMENT NODES"""

    displace = cmds.shadingNode('PxrDisplace', name='disp_' + shaderName, asShader=True)
    dispTransform = cmds.shadingNode('PxrDispTransform', name='dispTransform_' + shaderName, asTexture=True)
    pxrtexture_disp = cmds.shadingNode('PxrTexture', name='displacement_' + shaderName, asTexture=True)

    """ALBEDO"""

    cmds.connectAttr('%s.resultRGB' % remap, '%s.diffuseColor' % myShader)
    cmds.connectAttr('%s.resultRGB' % hsl, '%s.inputRGB' % remap)
    cmds.connectAttr('%s.resultRGB' % cc, '%s.inputRGB' % hsl)
    cmds.connectAttr('%s.resultRGB' % pxrtexture, '%s.inputRGB' % cc)

    """SPECULAR"""

    cmds.connectAttr('%s.resultRGB' % remap_spec, '%s.specularFaceColor' % myShader)
    cmds.connectAttr('%s.resultRGB' % hsl_spec, '%s.inputRGB' % remap_spec)
    cmds.connectAttr('%s.resultRGB' % cc_spec, '%s.inputRGB' % hsl_spec)
    cmds.connectAttr('%s.resultRGB' % pxrtexture_spec, '%s.inputRGB' % cc_spec)

    """ROUGHNESS"""

    cmds.connectAttr('%s.resultR' % remap_roughness, '%s.specularRoughness' % myShader)
    cmds.connectAttr('%s.resultRGB' % hsl_roughness, '%s.inputRGB' % remap_roughness)
    cmds.connectAttr('%s.resultRGB' % cc_roughness, '%s.inputRGB' % hsl_roughness)
    cmds.connectAttr('%s.resultRGB' % pxrtexture_roughness, '%s.inputRGB' % cc_roughness)

    """BUMP NORMAL"""

    cmds.connectAttr('%s.resultRGB' % pxrtexture_bump, '%s.inputRGB' % remap_bump_normal)
    cmds.connectAttr('%s.resultR' % remap_bump_normal, '%s.inputBump' % bump)
    cmds.connectAttr('%s.resultN' % bump, '%s.bumpNormal' % myShader)

    """DISPLACEMENT"""

    cmds.connectAttr('%s.resultR' % pxrtexture_disp, '%s.dispScalar' % dispTransform)
    cmds.connectAttr('%s.resultF' % dispTransform, '%s.dispScalar' % displace)
    cmds.connectAttr('%s.outColor' % displace, '%s.displacementShader' % myShaderSG)

    # PxrTexture attributes

    cmds.setAttr(pxrtexture + ".atlasStyle", 1)
    cmds.setAttr(pxrtexture + ".linearize", 1)

    # Specular attributes

    cmds.setAttr(pxrtexture_spec + ".atlasStyle", 1)

    # Roughness attributes

    cmds.setAttr(pxrtexture_roughness + ".atlasStyle", 1)

    # Bump and normal attributes

    cmds.setAttr(pxrtexture_bump + ".atlasStyle", 1)

    # Displacement attributes

    cmds.setAttr(pxrtexture_disp + ".atlasStyle", 1)
    cmds.setAttr(dispTransform + ".dispRemapMode", 2)

    # assign le shader a la selection
    for o in mySelectionList:
        cmds.sets(o, e=True, forceElement=myShaderSG)

    print('Renderman Shader assigned to object successfully')


def arnold_create_network(shaderName, selection_list, texture_dir):
    # create shader
    aiSts_node = cmds.shadingNode('aiStandardSurface', asShader=True, name=shaderName + "_Mtl")
    # create a shading group
    myShaderSG = cmds.sets(renderable=True, noSurfaceShader=True, empty=True, name=aiSts_node + "SG")
    # assign shader to shading group
    cmds.connectAttr('%s.outColor' % aiSts_node, '%s.surfaceShader' % myShaderSG)
    # assign shader to selection
    for o in selection_list:
        cmds.sets(o, e=True, forceElement=myShaderSG)

    # connect nodes ALBEDO
    myFile_Albedo = cmds.shadingNode("file", asTexture=True, name='albedo_' + aiSts_node)
    place2dtexture = cmds.shadingNode("place2dTexture", asTexture=True, name='Tile_Albedo_' + aiSts_node)
    rangeAlbedo = cmds.shadingNode("aiRange", asTexture=True, name='Range_Albedo_' + aiSts_node)
    colorCorrectAlbedo = cmds.shadingNode("aiColorCorrect", asTexture=True, name='ColorCorrect_Albedo_' + aiSts_node)
    # connect place2d texture to file node
    cmds.defaultNavigation(connectToExisting=True, source=place2dtexture, destination=myFile_Albedo)

    cmds.connectAttr(myFile_Albedo + ".outColor", colorCorrectAlbedo + ".input", force=True)
    cmds.connectAttr(colorCorrectAlbedo + ".outColor", rangeAlbedo + ".input", force=True)
    cmds.connectAttr(rangeAlbedo + ".outColor", aiSts_node + ".baseColor", force=True)

    # attributes
    cmds.setAttr(myFile_Albedo + ".uvTilingMode", 3)
    cmds.setAttr(myFile_Albedo + ".colorSpace", "sRGB", type='string')

    # connect nodes METALNESS
    myFile_Metalness = cmds.shadingNode("file", asTexture=True, name='metalness_' + aiSts_node)
    place2dtexture = cmds.shadingNode("place2dTexture", asTexture=True, name='Tile_Metalness_' + aiSts_node)
    rangeMetalness = cmds.shadingNode("aiRange", asTexture=True, name='Range_Metalness_' + aiSts_node)
    colorCorrectMetalness = cmds.shadingNode("aiColorCorrect", asTexture=True,
                                             name='ColorCorrect_Metalness_' + aiSts_node)
    # connect place2d texture to file node
    cmds.defaultNavigation(connectToExisting=True, source=place2dtexture, destination=myFile_Metalness)

    cmds.connectAttr(myFile_Metalness + ".outColor", colorCorrectMetalness + ".input", force=True)
    cmds.connectAttr(colorCorrectMetalness + ".outColor", rangeMetalness + ".input", force=True)
    cmds.connectAttr(rangeMetalness + ".outColorR", aiSts_node + ".metalness", force=True)

    # attributes
    cmds.setAttr(myFile_Metalness + ".uvTilingMode", 3)
    cmds.setAttr(myFile_Metalness + ".colorSpace", "Raw", type='string')

    # connect nodes SPECULAR
    myFile_SpecularWeight = cmds.shadingNode("file", asTexture=True, name='specular_' + aiSts_node)
    place2dtexture = cmds.shadingNode("place2dTexture", asTexture=True, name='Tile_Specular_' + aiSts_node)
    rangeSpecular = cmds.shadingNode("aiRange", asTexture=True, name='Range_Specular_' + aiSts_node)
    colorCorrectSpecular = cmds.shadingNode("aiColorCorrect", asTexture=True,
                                            name='ColorCorrect_Specular_' + aiSts_node)
    # connect place2d texture to file node
    cmds.defaultNavigation(connectToExisting=True, source=place2dtexture, destination=myFile_SpecularWeight)

    cmds.connectAttr(myFile_SpecularWeight + ".outColor", colorCorrectSpecular + ".input", force=True)
    cmds.connectAttr(colorCorrectSpecular + ".outColor", rangeSpecular + ".input", force=True)
    cmds.connectAttr(rangeSpecular + ".outColorR", aiSts_node + ".specular", force=True)

    # attributes
    cmds.setAttr(myFile_SpecularWeight + ".uvTilingMode", 3)
    cmds.setAttr(myFile_SpecularWeight + ".colorSpace", "Raw", type='string')

    # connect nodes ROUGHNESS
    myFile_Roughness = cmds.shadingNode("file", asTexture=True, name='roughness_' + aiSts_node)
    place2dtexture = cmds.shadingNode("place2dTexture", asTexture=True, name='Tile_Roughness_' + aiSts_node)
    rangeRoughness = cmds.shadingNode("aiRange", asTexture=True, name='Range_Roughness_' + aiSts_node)
    colorCorrectRoughness = cmds.shadingNode("aiColorCorrect", asTexture=True,
                                             name='ColorCorrect_Roughness_' + aiSts_node)
    # connect place2d texture to file node
    cmds.defaultNavigation(connectToExisting=True, source=place2dtexture, destination=myFile_Roughness)

    cmds.connectAttr(myFile_Roughness + ".outColor", colorCorrectRoughness + ".input", force=True)
    cmds.connectAttr(colorCorrectRoughness + ".outColor", rangeRoughness + ".input", force=True)
    cmds.connectAttr(rangeRoughness + ".outColorR", aiSts_node + ".specularRoughness", force=True)

    # attributes
    cmds.setAttr(myFile_Roughness + ".uvTilingMode", 3)
    cmds.setAttr(myFile_Roughness + ".colorSpace", "Raw", type='string')

    # connect nodes BUMP
    myFile_Bump = cmds.shadingNode("file", asTexture=True, name='bump_' + aiSts_node)
    place2dtexture = cmds.shadingNode("place2dTexture", asTexture=True, name='Tile_Bump_' + aiSts_node)
    rangeBump = cmds.shadingNode("aiRange", asTexture=True, name='Range_Bump_' + aiSts_node)
    colorCorrectBump = cmds.shadingNode("aiColorCorrect", asTexture=True, name='ColorCorrect_Bump_' + aiSts_node)
    bump = cmds.shadingNode("aiBump2d", asShader=True, name='BumpSettings_' + aiSts_node)

    """ Mette le defaultNavigation"""  # TODO

    # attributes
    cmds.setAttr(myFile_Bump + ".uvTilingMode", 3)
    cmds.setAttr(myFile_Bump + ".colorSpace", "Raw", type='string')

    # connect nodes DISPLACEMENT
    myFile_Displacement = cmds.shadingNode("file", asTexture=True, name='displacement_' + aiSts_node)
    place2dtexture = cmds.shadingNode("place2dTexture", asTexture=True, name='Tile_Displacement_' + aiSts_node)
    rangeDisp = cmds.shadingNode("aiRange", asTexture=True, name='Range_Displacement_' + aiSts_node)
    colorCorrectDisp = cmds.shadingNode("aiColorCorrect", asTexture=True,
                                        name='ColorCorrect_Displacement_' + aiSts_node)
    displace = cmds.shadingNode("displacementShader", asShader=True, name='DisplacementSettings_' + aiSts_node)

    """ Mette le defaultNavigation"""  # TODO

    cmds.connectAttr(myFile_Displacement + ".outColor", colorCorrectDisp + ".input", force=True)
    cmds.connectAttr(colorCorrectDisp + ".outColor", rangeDisp + ".input", force=True)
    cmds.connectAttr(rangeDisp + ".outColorR", displace + ".displacement", force=True)
    cmds.connectAttr(displace + ".displacement", myShaderSG + ".displacementShader", force=True)

    # attributes
    cmds.setAttr(myFile_Displacement + ".uvTilingMode", 3)
    cmds.setAttr(myFile_Displacement + ".colorSpace", "Raw", type='string')

    print('Arnold Shader assigned to object successfully')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ui = UI()
    ui.show_window()
    print('Happy Texturing!')
```

[UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdvnW.png)

Comment: Not sure what problems you have. First you need a way to define the sourceimages directory, maybe a button in your UI which calls the get_texture_path() function. And then you can read the directory and analyze the files.

Answer (score 0):

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

tex_file = "c:/tex/map.png"

fileNode = cmds.shadingNode("file", asTexture=True, isColorManaged=True)

cmds.setAttr("{}.fileTextureName".format(fileNode), tex_file, type="string")
```

[image]

cmds.setAttr("file1.fileTextureName", "c:/tex/map.png")

Comment: Please consider adding more context/information why your code could be useful to the OP (since the problem is actually not clear).

Comment: I think William just wants to fill an image path to a Maya file node.